# Unable to access file using .Net Core 3 or .Net Framework on Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, windows, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

My new projects generated by VS 2019 cannot read or write files. Even the following simple code does not work.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hello");

        string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
        UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
        string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
        var folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

        var filePath = Path.Combine(folder, "test.txt");
        Console.WriteLine(filePath);
        
        // File.WriteAllLines(filePath, new[] { "hello" });
        
        using (var f = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            f.Write(new byte[] { 0x39 }, 0, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Accessing files using

- .Net Core 3.0 + debugger
- .Net Core 3.0 + generated exe
- .Net Framework 4.6.2, 4.8 (have not tested others)

gives the exception

```
Unhandled exception. System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\user\Documents\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\test.txt' is denied.
```

However, it works in .Net Core 2.2 or below or using `dotnet ConsoleApp1.dll`.

My other few years old projects work. I have never encountered such a problem before. What is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_IO_FileStream__ctor_System_String_System_IO_FileMode_) says that `UnauthorizedAccessException` will be thrown when file is read-only. You may add `FileAccess.Read` or `FileAccess.ReadWrite`

Comment: I have tried `FileAccess` but it is the same. The file did not get created.

Comment: Your code actually works. There must be another application that is using that file or the folder is read-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out my anti-virus blocked the file access. There were no pop-ups the first day so I could not know. Later, there were finally popups.